# Simplify the following Boolean expression.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science, boolean-algebra

Can someone explain to me how this step done? I got a different answer than what the solution said.

Simplify $x(y+z)(\bar{x} + y)(\bar{y} + x + z)$

what the solution got

$x(y+z)(\bar{x} + y)(\bar{y} + x + z)$ = $x(y + z\bar{x})(\bar{y} + x + z)$ (Using distrubitive)

What I got

$x(y+z)(\bar{x} + y)(\bar{y} + x + z)$ = $x(y\bar{x} + y + z\bar{x} + zy)(\bar{y} + x + z)$ (Using distrubitive)

Comment: The part of the solution you quote is only the first step in the simplification.  If you switch the second and third terms, it is apparent that the simplest form is $xy$ and that applying distributivity to $x$ and $(\bar{x} + y)$ first is the most expedient way to start.

Comment: got it! thanks i am new at this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y\bar{x} + y + z\bar{x} + zy$

=  $y(\bar{x} + 1) + z\bar{x} + zy$

= $y + z\bar{x} + zy$

= $y(1 + z) + z\bar{x}$

= $y + z\bar{x}$

**Direct rule -**

X + YZ = (X+Y)(X+Z)

So we have -

$(y + z)(y + \bar x)$

= $(y + z \bar x)$

Comment: Your welcome...

Answer (score 1):

Put the following equivalence into your boolean algebra toolkit:

**Absorption**

$x +xy = x$

Using Absorption twice in one step we get:

$y\bar{x}+y+z\bar{x}+zy = y+z\bar{x}$

Done!

Answer (score -1):

Hint : $ab + ac = a(b+c) = a$ and $a+a=a$.
Do you see the '$b$' and '$c$' (and also the '$a$') in your case?